# Jquery Ajax Autocomplete, text is changing

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

The autocomplete is working but when I enter a search and select an option, the value that appears in the text box changes to the value rather than leave what has been entered.  How do I prevent what you have entered into the box from changing?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Name").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/starsearch/starindex",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { Prefix: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {                          
                        return { label: item.Name, value: item.Filename };
                    }))

                }
            })
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('#idBox').html('<a href="/star/' + ui.item.value +'">' + ui.item.label + '</a>');
        },
        messages: {
            noResults: "", results: ""
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

Select event is triggered when you select item and default action is to replace the text field's value with the value of the selected item.

You can prevent default action by  `event.preventDefault();`

try below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Name").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/starsearch/starindex",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { Prefix: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {                          
                        return { label: item.Name, value: item.Filename };
                    }))

                }
            })
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#idBox').html('<a href="/star/' + ui.item.value +'">' + ui.item.label + '</a>');
        },
        messages: {
            noResults: "", results: ""
        }
    });
})
```